# Java regex aritmetic operators occurence

Tags: java, regex

I have a little problem with regex in Java. I try make regex, which will be match aritmetic operations. 
It is my regex:

```
[\d]*[-+*/^][\d]*([-+*/^][\d]*)*
```

It should accept string like 34+45*5^7/3-5, but it also accepts strings like 34+-/^34. I don't know what is wrong in this regex.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: You need to replace some `*` (zero or more) with `+` (one or more): `\d+([-+*/^]\d+)*`. Remember to double ``\`` when in a Java string literal: `"\\d+([-+*/^]\\d+)*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex and let me know if there are any issues :-

```
[\d]+([\-\+\*/][\d]+)*
```

Comment: I adapted your regex. I use this ([\\d]+[\\-\\+\\*/\\^][\\d]+)+ and it works. Thank you.

Comment: That won't work. `1+5+7` will not match, because the repeating group has to both start and end with a digit. You also dropped the `^`. Besides that, `\d` doesn't need to be in a character class (`[]`), and `-`, `+`, and `*` don't need escaping inside a character class. It should be `\d+([-+*/^]\d+)*`

Comment: Yeah, this will take even number of operands,thanks for pointing it out +1

Comment: How would you differentiate between [1-9] and [+-/] , if you don't use escape sequences?

Comment: By putting the `-` first or last, and OP has it first, so it works. Same for the `^`, which only has special meaning if first, so by not putting it first, you don't have to escape. `+`, `?`, `.`, `*`, etc. don't have special meaning in a character class, in any position, so they never have to be escaped there.

Answer (score 2):

The star accepts 0 to n times the expression. In your case it is possible to have a number followed by an Operator followed by an optional number (because of the star) which can be followed by another Operator so if the optional number misses the RegEx still matches.
Try using the + instead of *.
+ requires Ast least one occurence.